# Partitioning $k$-subsets into disjoint groups

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

I want the following result:

> For any $k\ge 1$ and $n$ large enough, there is a large number $N(n,k)$ (I believe that $N(n,k) = \lfloor n/k\rfloor -1$, but  $C(k)\cdot n$  with $C(k)>0$ independent of $n$ would be fine)
> such that all $k$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ can be partitioned into several groups so that each group consists of at least $N(n,k)$ pairwise disjoint subsets.

I am actually able to prove this with $C(k) = 1/2k$, but this sounds too classical, so I would welcome a reference.

Comment: This is confused. $C(k)$ is nowhere defined. Cutting out some useless notation, are you asking whether for $k\in\Bbb N$ there exists a positive constant $C$ such that for sufficiently large $n$ the set $\binom{\{1,\ldots,n\}}k$ can be partitioned into parts so that every part contains a subset of at least $Ckn$ disjoint subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen is it clearer now? By useless notation you mean $N(n,k)$ I guess. Well, it is not useless for me: as I wrote, I suspect the result holds for $N(n,k) = \lfloor n/k\rfloor -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in Theorem 2 of the article [The edge-coloring of complete hypergraphs I](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895679900029)

Specifically, set in this theorem $r=n, m=1, h=k$, write
${n\choose k} = s_1\cdot  \lfloor n/k\rfloor  + s_2\cdot  (\lfloor n/k\rfloor-1)$ for some nonnegative integers $s_1, s_2$, put $s = s_1 + s_2$, $a_1 = \dots = a_{s_1} = \lfloor n/k\rfloor$, $a_{s_1+1} = \dots = a_{s} = \lfloor n/k\rfloor - 1$. Applying Theorem 2 gives the partition of edges of the complete hypergraph $K^k_n$, equivalently, the partition of all $k$-subsets of $[n]$, into sets $E_1,\dots, E_s$ such that, for each hypergraph $([n], E_i)$, the valency of each vertex is approximately $k\lfloor n/k\rfloor/n$ or $k(\lfloor n/k\rfloor-1)/n$, i.e. $0$ or $1$, equivalently, for each collection $E_i$ of $k$-subsets, each $x\in[n]$ belongs to at most one of them.