Conjecture: $N-$subsets of a $kN$ set can be arranged as groups of partitions
Inspired by this question.
From a set of $M = k N$ elements,  consider the $\binom{M}{N}$ subsets of size $N$. Prove (or disprove) that they can be arranged as a matrix such that every row contains $k$ subsets, and where each row is a partition of the original set (i.e., the subsets inside a row are disjoint, i.e. they cover the full set).

Update (from references from the accepted answer). This type of problem has a rich history, eg the fifteen schoolgirls problem (1850). The conjecture was apparently stated in 1973 and solved (in the affirmative) in 1975.

For $N=2$ this is true as it is just a round robin tournament. The $k=2$ case is trivial, so the smallest interesting case is $M=12$, $N=3$.

@JaapScherphuis Why not $ M = 9, N = 3$? Or am I missing something?

Related question, asking about partitioning $k$-subsets of ${1,\dots,n}$, without requiring $n$ to be a multiple of $k$, and having slacker requirements on each group to make this possible: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483501/partitioning-k-subsets-into-disjoint-groups

The referenced paper in Mike's link states that is a classical problem, and the answer is "Yes it can be". The author proved it in  Z. BARANYAI, On the factorisation of the complete uniform hypergraph.

@CalvinLin Doh! You're right of course. For some reason my brain insisted on distinct factors.

Your question is answered by this paper: The edge-coloring of complete hypergraphs.
First sentence of the abstract:

This paper contains and generalizes the solution of the following classical
problem:
If $h\mid n$ then the $h$-element subsets of an $n$-element set can be partitioned
into $\binom{n-1}{h-1}$ classes so that every class contains $n/h$ disjoint $h$-element sets and every
$h$-element set appears in exactly one class.

